# Search element in a JSONArray in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a JSONArray in Java like this:
    ["1","2","45","354"]
Then, I want to search for an element into this array. For example, to check if "44" is into the array. I try

```
boolean flag = false;
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
  if (jsonArray[i]= myElementToSearch){
    flag = true;
  }
}
```

But I cant get an error, because It has results in an Array, not in a JSONArray

How can I comprobe if an element is present in a JSONArray?

myElementToSearch is a String

Comment: What is the type of `myElementToSearch`?

Comment: And what is the type of jsonArray? Is it http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html?

Comment: Yes, it is. myElementToSearch is a String and jsonArray is a  json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html

Comment: You can access the elements in a JSONArray by using an index
eg. jsonArray.get(index)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
boolean found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
    if (jsonArray.getString(i).equals(myElementToSearch))
        found = true;
```

I assume that `jsonArray` has type http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html.

Answer (score 2):

If the object you are comparing against is a primitive type (e.g. `int`) then try *comparing* instead of assigning the value.

```
// Comparing
if (jsonArray[i] == myElementToSearch)
```

vs

```
// Assigning
if (jsonArray[i] = myElementToSearch)
```

If it is an object, such as a `String` the `equals`-method should be used for comparing:

```
// Comparing objects (not primitives)
if (myElementToSearch.equals(jsonArray[i]))
```

And, if the array is a `org.json.JSONArray` you use the following for accessing the values:

```
myElementToSearch.equals(jsonArray.getString(i))
```

Comment: I get the error: array required, but JSONArray found

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
boolean flag = false;
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
  if (jsonArray.get(i).toString().equals(myElementToSearch)){
    flag = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

Note that I added "break", so that, if your element is found, it doesn't keep looking for it.